# How to show Taskpane selected data in ribbon command using officejs

Tags: excel, office-js, excel-addins

We are populating list of users in dropdown list Task pane UI. When we are selecting the user in the list we were able to show selected user in taskpane itself.
Also we wanted to show the selected user in ribbon command Menu like in attached screen shot.
The screen shot which took from Excel DNA with .net application the same wanted to achieve in Excel add-in using OfficeJS.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The Fluent UI extensibility level leaves much to be a desire for Web add-ins. See [Add-in commands for Excel, PowerPoint, and Word](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/design/add-in-commands#command-capabilities) for more information.

If you need to implement dynamic ribbon customizations you need to consider developing a VSTO based add-in instead.

Comment: @eugene....is this feature still not available in Office JS Excel add-in?

Answer (score 0):

this feature is not yet available with add-in commands. One capability we just announced on the community call was "contextual tabs api". This will be available soon for public preview where you will be able to test it. Please stay tuned for our next community call for an update.